# Access SQL Combining Multiple Columns and Summing Another Column Pivoting on Combined Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (note: imported from Excel used by associates) in Access that contains something like this:

```
Associate | Date_Of_First_Call | Date_of_Second_Call | Date_of_Third_Call
Amy       | 07/18/2017         | 07/19/2017          | 07/20/2017
Brian     | 07/18/2017         | 07/18/2017          | 07/20/2017
Amy       | 07/18/2017         | 07/20/2017          |
Carl      | 07/19/2017         | 07/20/2017          | 07/21/2017
```

I am very much new to SQL and from what I learned so far...

```
SELECT Date_Of_First_Call AS CallDate,
SUM(IIF(Associate ="Amy", 1, 0)) AS Amy,
SUM(IIF(Associate= "Brian", 1, 0)) AS Brian,
SUM(IIF(Associate="Carl", 1, 0)) AS Carl,
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Date_Of_First_Call
UNION
SELECT Date_Of_Second_Call AS CallDate,
SUM(IIF(Associate ="Amy", 1, 0)) AS Amy,
SUM(IIF(Associate= "Brian", 1, 0)) AS Brian,
SUM(IIF(Associate="Carl", 1, 0)) AS Carl,
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Date_Of_Second_Call
UNION
SELECT Date_Of_Third_Call AS CallDate,
SUM(IIF(Associate ="Amy", 1, 0)) AS Amy,
SUM(IIF(Associate= "Brian", 1, 0)) AS Brian,
SUM(IIF(Associate="Carl", 1, 0)) AS Carl,
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Date_Of_Third_Call
```

Gives me:

```
Call Date  | Amy | Brian | Carl
07/18/2017 | 2   | 1     |
07/18/2017 |     | 1     |
07/19/2017 |     |       | 1
07/19/2017 | 1   |       |
07/20/2017 | 1   |       | 1
07/20/2017 | 1   | 1     |
07/21/2017 |     |       | 1
```

Close! But I would like this below instead:

```
Call Date  | Amy | Brian | Carl
07/18/2017 | 2   | 2     |
07/19/2017 | 1   |       | 1
07/20/2017 | 2   |1      | 1
07/21/2017 |     |       | 1
```

FYI: I could get result above, if I created three separate Transform/Pivot queries and unioning them into one, but that requires a total of four queries. So, if there is a way to do it in just one that would be amazing! Thank you!

Comment: You should really read into database normalisation. It's a truly bad practice to store essentially similar information in different columns in the tables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Erik. However, the only common information with those three columns are that they are of a date type. Each column signifies the date an associate called someone and they are given three chances to reach someone: 1) Call of First Date, 2) Call of Second Date, and 3) Call of Third Date.

Comment: They all reference calls, do they not? The fact that you want to sum them implies that they're related. Most `UNION` queries are an indicator of non-normalized data. And you're running into trouble because of this. If you were to store this normalized, the operation would require less steps, as I'm about to demonstrate. If you wanted to perform an operation on the call dates (eg a correction for a certain timezone) it's likely you will have to apply it to all these columns, while you should only have to apply it to one. Properly normalized, the constraint of max 3 calls would be lifted.

Comment: Yes, they do reference calls, but for three different attempts. The associates use an Excel spreadsheet to track each attempt with a separate column. If there is a way to show this as one column in the spreadsheet, that owuld be amazing. But for now, its in three columns. So, yes, it would be great to see your demonstration!

Comment: Ah, well, data imported from Excel is rarely normalized. It's good practice to use the first step of my answer to normalize the data, and insert that in a table for further queries. But if you're running regular imports, you might just leave it as a query, and write other queries of it (writing queries on normalized data is often way easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we're going to normalize the data, this query will be used later as a subquery:

```
SELECT Associate, date_of_first_call as CallDate
FROM table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT Associate, date_of_second_call as CallDate
FROM table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT Associate, date_of_third_call as CallDate
FROM table_name
```

This is the normalized way of storing data in a table (you can include a number to reference if it's the first, second or third call).

Now, let's crosstab:

```
TRANSFORM Count(A.CallDate) AS CountOfCallDate
SELECT A.CallDate
FROM (
    SELECT Associate, date_of_first_call as CallDate
    FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Associate, date_of_second_call as CallDate
    FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Associate, date_of_third_call as CallDate
    FROM table_name
) As A
GROUP BY A.CallDate
PIVOT A.Associate
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help! It works perfectly! And now I somewhat understand normalization. Also FYI, I changed "A.CountOfCallDate" to "CountOfCallDate", due to a syntax error in the TRANSFORMATION statement.